# The auth user returns null in redirect method

Tags: php, redirect, registration, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to redirect the users to certain routes based on user roles, however the `auth()->user()` returns null. This is authentication using laravel 5.8. Can someone explain what is going on?, I'm new to php and laravel.

If you have resources that details these authentication processes please share

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //public $redirectTo = '/home';
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        $role = auth()->user()->role;
        //dd($role);
        if ($role === 'candidate') {
            return '/candidate-register';
        }else if ($role === 'employer') {
            return '/employer_dashboard';
        }else if ($role === 'contractor') {
            return '/contractor_dashboard';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        try {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'role' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            ]);
        } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException  $th) {
            return back()->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(Request $data)
    {
        //$this->validator($data, []);
        try {
            User::create([
                'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
                'role' => $data['role'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
            return $this->redirectTo();
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $th) {
            //dd($th->getMessage());
            return redirect('/register')->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
        }
    }


}
```

I want the users to return to the path specified in the redirect method

Comment: If those are authorized routes in redirectTo method you might want to put Auth::check() first

Comment: @ViperTecPro can you explain a little, I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Just do this,

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
        if (Auth::guard()->check() === true) {
            $role = auth()->user()->role;
            if ($role === 'candidate') {
                return '/candidate';
            }else if ($role === 'employer') {
                return '/employer';
            }else if ($role === 'contractor') {
                return '/contractor';
            }
        }
        return '/';
}
protected function create(array $data)
{
   $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'role'  => $data['role'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
   return $user;
}
```

This is my **web\route.php** file I tested with these routes

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'prefix'     => 'employer'
],function(){
    Route::get('/','HomeController@employerDashboard')->name('employer');
    //......Other routes having employer prefix in the url
});

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'prefix'     => 'candidate'
],function(){
    Route::get('/','HomeController@candidateDashboard')->name('candidate');
    //......Other routes having employer prefix in the url
});

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'prefix'     => 'contractor'
],function(){
    Route::get('/','HomeController@contractorDashboard')->name('contractor');
    //......Other routes having contractor prefix in the url
});
```

Comment: Thank you, your response helped me understand better.

Comment: It does, I'll share my modifications as answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

1. The Auth facade wasn't imported, therefore it wasn't available within the controller, hence it returned null.
2. By the code written in the controller the user was getting created but not yet authenticated, hence they can't access the route.

I added:

1. The Auth facade to grant access within the RegisterController
2. `Auth::login($user)` so users are authenticated after registration

Like I mentioned earlier, I'm new to the framework and slowly learning from the docs.

See the working code below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    use RegistersUsers;


    protected function redirectTo()
    {
       if(Auth::guard()->check() === true){
        $role = auth()->user()->role;

        if ($role === 'candidate') {
            return redirect('candidate-register');
        }else if ($role === 'employer') {
            return redirect('employer-register');
        }else if ($role === 'contractor') {
            return redirect('contractor-register');
        }
       }
        return redirect('register');;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    protected function create(Request $data)
    {
        try {

            $this->validate($data, [
                'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'role' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            ]);


            $user = User::create([
                'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
                'role' => $data['role'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
            Auth::login($user);
            return $this->redirectTo();
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $th) {
            return redirect('register')->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```